# '90 alfa 164 V6 3.0 12v bad idle when hot / hard to start / bad rev under 2000 rpm

Tags: rough-idle, idle

I am getting a bad idle when the engine aforementioned is warm.
Can somebody please help me troubleshoot this problem ?
Here are the parameters when the engine is idling rough

[image: Alfa 164 3.0 v6 parameters when hot]
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

update : idle control valve grommet was the problem : intake box is made of aluminium which expands when hot, grommet was old and shrunk and that was together creating a vacuum leak

Comment: Thanks for the update, but in the future please edit your original post - do not provide an update as an "answer".  Cheers!